# Is it possible to prevent the outer transaction context from rollback even after a exception that marked as rollBackFor thrown?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-transactions, transactional

Suppose a user signup process like this:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Resource
    private EmailService emailService;
    @Resource 
    private Jmstemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void signUp(User user) {

        //save user to DB, etc

        postSignUp(User user);
    }

    /**
     * Business that not so important
     * suppose this method may throw any exception
     * 
    **/
    public void postSignUp(User user) {
        emailService.sendEmail(user);
        jmsTemplate.sendSignUpEvent(user);
        ...
    }

}
```

We make the signUp() method as transactional. if any exception thrown within signUp() method, the transaction will rollback.

And of course, any exception thrown within postSignUp() will also result in the rollback of the transaction.

But, since the logic in postSignUp() was not so important, I wonder how can I prevent the outer transaction from rollback even a exception was thrown within the postSignUp() method?

Comment: You possibly could surround your `postSignUp(User user);` call with a `try/catch` block to handle any exception during that call. Question is more like if the user can't log in, is it worth recording the event?

Comment: It is feasible. Any other elegant way except use `try/catch`?

Comment: True, exception handling isn't particularly elegant, but it is mandatory for clean code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `noRollbackFor` property of `Transactional`?

It goes like:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=SampleCustomException.class)
```

Comment: But postSignUp() may throw any exception, and I don't like surrounding the whole method with try/catch and re-throw it as a custom exception.

Comment: This is a clean way of coding, though